# How to iterate over a range asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.6

In python3.6, if I want to iterate over a range, I can simply do this

```
for i in range(100): pass
```

However, what should I do if I want to iterate over a range asynchronously? I can not do

```
async for i in range(100): pass # Doesn't work
```

because `range` is not an `AsyncIterable` object. One solution I can think about is to subclass range and define `__aiter__` method. However it feels really not pythonic for me. Is there any good way/library to do this **without** defining my own class?

Comment: Why do you need iterate over `range()` asynchronously? There aren't anything asynchronous on `range()`.

Comment: I have a multi-level nested for-loop. The innermost one has async operation. However when I run the loop the outer-layers don't really behave asynchronously.

Comment: That indicates some other problem, maybe how your code is structured. I fear making `range()` async wouldn't help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-generator-object

an example function you can use instead range():

```
async def async_range(count):
    for i in range(count):
        yield(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0)
```

Comment: The PEP also tells to `await asyncio.sleep(delay)`. Is this not needed?

Comment: Yes, it is needed to relinquish control. Do an `await asyncio.sleep(0)`

Comment: in Python 3.11,IDE will tips you `expect type AsyncIterable,got  range instead `

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
async def myrange(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop:
        range_ = range(start, stop, step)
    else:
        range_ = range(start)
    for i in range_:
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Comment: It gives control back to the event loop so other code can run.

Comment: It would have been better to just use `*args` and then feed it to range... You can also call it `arange` by the way ("a" for async).

Comment: @YahyaAbouImran using *args would give slightly shorter code, however explicitly naming the arguments gives more information to the caller (and the ide) and I thus prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Definition:

```
class asyncrange:

    class __asyncrange:
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.__iter_range = iter(range(*args))

        async def __anext__(self):
            try:
                return next(self.__iter_range)           
            except StopIteration as e:
                raise StopAsyncIteration(str(e))

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.__args = args

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self.__asyncrange(*self.__args)
```

Using:

```
async for i in asyncrange(100, 10, -10):
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
```